# How to access homebanking? with post and httplib

Tags: python, ssl

My objective is to gain access to my homebanking to carry out a control of expenses. The problem is that I always get a code `302`, maybe because I sent a bad the user and key. Is the following a correct way of sending the head with post ssl?

```
import httplib

host = 'www.bancoprovincia.bancainternet.com.ar'
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
conn.set_debuglevel(1)
conn.putrequest("POST", "/eBanking/login")
header = {'accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6', 
'accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'content-Type': 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36'}

for k, v in header.iteritems():
    conn.putheader(k, v)

user = '##'
passwd = '##'
conn.endheaders()
conn.send('usuario:'+user+'clave:'+passwd)
res = conn.getresponse()

print res.status
print res.getheaders()
```

Here is the response from the server

```
send: 'POST /eBanking/login HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.bancoprovincia.bancainternet.com.ar\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\ncontent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\naccept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\r\naccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\naccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nuser-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36\r\n\r\n'
send: 'usuario:##:clave##'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Movido tempor\xe1lmente\r\n'
header: Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 19:40:18 GMT
header: Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Red Hat Enterprise Web Server)
header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=696BA6EB7C85B74476817A42C211ED29.tcc1; Path=/eBanking; Secure
header: Location: https://www.bancoprovincia.bancainternet.com.ar/eBanking/login/inicio.htm;jsessionid=696BA6EB7C85B74476817A42C211ED29.tcc1?login_error=1
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Connection: close
header: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
302
```

Comment: gracias por la edicion, my English grammar is missing

Answer (score 0):

See the location header in the response?
The server tells you you should use that URI
For more info, see [http status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: I understand the point of 301, but always leaves 301, why I ask, if the user's shipping and key is good or bad.

Comment: the name of the username input is "j_username" and the name of the password control is "j_password". Maybe try changing the name of these controls

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend the use of the requests module, it's really easy to use